# alineando los contenedores hijos con Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estoy intentando centrar un contenedor de manera que este quede en medio de todo. Sin embargo no lo he logrado, siempre se queda en la parte superior (top) del contenedor padre.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --dark-gray: #8c8c8c;
  --very-dark-gray: #696969;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__img--logo {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.header__img--hamburger {
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}


.hero-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70rem;

  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("../images/mobile/image-hero.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero-text {
  width: 32rem;
  min-height: 24rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid var(--white);
  color: var(--white);
}

.hero-text > h1 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.3cm;
  transform: translate(0, -20%);
}
```

```html
<main>
<section class="hero-section">
  <header class="header">
    <img class="header__img--logo" src="./images/logo.svg"  />

    <img class="header__img--hamburger" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg"/>
  </header>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>IMMERSIVE EXPERIENCES THAT DELIVER</h1>
  </div>
</section>
</main>
```

Esto me genera el siguiente comportamiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que busco es que ese contenedor sea alineado en el centro de todo el contenedor principal. ¿Alguna idea de como lograr?

Comment: vertical y horizontalmente no?

Comment: Si, vertical y horizontal, creo que no lo agregue en la pregunta :$

Comment: ¿Porque tienes un ``transform: translate(0, -20%);`` en el h1?

Comment: Ah, cierto. Eso lo tenia antes porque usaba Absolute y en un ejemplo lo usaba. Se me olvido removerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opción 1(*la menos recomendada ya que aunque reducimos la cantidad de reglas para lograr el objetivo, estamos de cierta manera forzando con un nodo que finalmente queda ahi sin mayor uso semántico y beneficio*)

- Trabajamos con *flexbox* a:

  - El contenedor principal que sería el que tiene la clase `hero-section` de modo que podamos distribuir a los elementos como cajas flexibles

    - En este sentido podemos agregar un tercer nodo que nos sirva para mantener un espacio ocupado al final, así cuando hagamos la separación el texto no quedará pegado al borde inferior sino que respetará y dejará libre el espacio de dicho elemento
  - Del mismo modo al contenedor con la clase `header` para hacer que sus elementos internos (*las imágenes*) se vuelvan cajas flexibles

Toma en cuenta que:

- Si usé *flex-direction* pero sobre el contenedor principal para que sean los contenedores de imágenes y texto los que queden uno sobre otro de forma vertical

Código de muestra:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .hero-section {
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .header {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <main>
    <section class="hero-section">
      <header class="header">
        <img class="header__img--logo" src="./images/logo.svg"  />

        <img class="header__img--hamburger" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg"/>
      </header>
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>IMMERSIVE EXPERIENCES THAT DELIVER</h1>
      </div>
      <span></span>
    </section>
    </main>
```

Opción 2 (**que personalmente puedo recomendar mas**).

En esta segunda opción, propongo:

- Sacar del contenedor `main` al `header` para que la distribución que hagamos con flexbox dentro del `hero-section` solo afecte a la caja flexible del `h1` lo cual *debería suponer facilitar y agilizar el trabajo*
- Dejamos antes del `main` al `header`para que igualmente podamos aplicar ahi *flexbox* pero que esto solo afecte a las cajas flexibles que en este caso son las imágenes

Nota.

Para esta última propuesta *lo considero como válido*, pues según la MDN y cito<sup>1</sup>

> El elemento HTML `<main>` representa el contenido principal del  de un documento o aplicación. El área principal del contenido consiste en el contenido que está directamente relacionado, o se expande sobre el tema central de un documento o la funcionalidad central de una aplicación. Este contenido debe ser único al documento, excluyendo cualquier contenido que se repita a través de un conjunto de documentos como barras laterales, enlaces de navegación, información de derechos de autor, logos del sitio y formularios de búsqueda (a menos, claro, que la función principal del documento sea un formulario de búsqueda).

Código:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .header {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .hero-section {
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
    
    <header class="header">
        <img class="header__img--logo" src="./images/logo.svg"  />
    
        <img class="header__img--hamburger" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg"/>
    </header>
    <main>
    <section class="hero-section">
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>IMMERSIVE EXPERIENCES THAT DELIVER</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    </main>
```

**Referencia**

- [Tag `main`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/main#resumen)
- [Cajas flexibles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS)
- [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: Gracias viejo, tengo una pregunta ¿Porqué  cuando no agregas el span todo se va hasta abajo? Me causo curiosidad eso 3:

Comment: Por que la distribución de los elementos solo considera a los existentes y sobre ellos trabaja, de todos modos editaré para colocar otra propuesta, @EdgarGc de todos modos te invito a no marcar como aceptada esta respuesta pues estoy seguro habrá mejores aportes